# Python output to text

Tags: pipe, output

I want to get the output of this tiny script in a .txt file, for example,

```
a = input ('what is your first name')
b = input ('what is your last name')
print ('Hello ' a + b )
```

The result is Hello blah blah, the question is, how to save the answer to a .txt or htm file... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use shell redirection. e.g `python your_script > output.txt`

Comment: I tried it, didn't work, I also want to print only the results not the questions (Hello first last). Is there something like print (' a + b ') >> new.txt ?

Comment: Why dont you use file handling in that case